# Resizing LDPC Parity Matrices

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

I am having a hard time trying to understand different optimizations for LDPC codes. Most important, I am finding it hard to understand how to compare different codes, given their lengths. 
For example, MacKay is a relevant author in this field, and co-authored multiples papers in the field, such as

- *Davey, Hllatthew C., and David JC MacKay. "Low density parity check codes over GF (q)." Information Theory Workshop, 1998. IEEE, 1998.*

You can find the parity-matrices for his codes, as well as other authors, [publicly available](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/codes/matrices/).

Even though sometimes these matrices share the same rate (Number of rows/number of columns), they are applied to codes with different lengths. This makes it harder to compare them, since most applications would have a block length already defined. In my view, it would be easier to adapt the code to the application, not the other way around.

My question is whether it is possible to resize these matrices, while keeping their coding properties. For instance, if I had a  matrix(N x K) with N=1000 and K=500, would it be possible for me to scale it down to N2 = 100 and K2=50.

Comment: My very limited experience with LDPC codes leaves me undecided. The instances of such scaling does not usually lead to optimal results. OTOH you may be able to keep the row/column weight distribution which should be good. But only if the resulting Tanner graph does not have short cycles. The other remark I want to make is that $N_2=100$ is probably too short for a good LDPC code, but my limited experience shows...

Comment: Thanks for the Input, Jyrky. My experience is way more limited.
I tried some LDPC codes for lower code lengths ( N ~ 100 ). I did not realize the block length would be a problem, but it does make sense. For lower block lengths I had more success with  parity-check matrices using regular distribution.